# Default params in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, default-parameters

I want to create a function with default params, but I want to use one default param and then use a custom value for the following one. For instance,

```
function greet(name, greeting = 'Hey', question = 'How are you?') {
    console.log(`${greeting}, ${name}! ${question}`);
  }

greet('Jack', , 'You good?'); // tried this, doesn't work :(
```

What if I wanted to say, "Hey, Jack! You good?", where I use the default for the first param with a default value, but not the second? I have tried calling the function with nothing between the commas in the function call. Is there a way to do this in JS without explicitly passing 'Hey', the defined default value, to the param that has a default already assigned?

Comment: You could pass through `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function greet(name, greeting = 'Hey', question = 'How are you?') {
    console.log(`${greeting}, ${name}! ${question}`);
  }

greet('Jack',undefined , 'You good?');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `undefined` for the second param. It should work as you expect it to be.

```js
greet('Jack', undefined, 'You good?');
```